# Converting a JSON/dictionary into a dataframe

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have the following output from a certain API service:

```
{'node': [{u'A': 300, 'B': u'Ken', u'C': 101901}, {u'A': 400, u'B': u'Miki', u'C': 500001}]}
```

Is this JSON or dictionary?
How can I convert this to something like this?

```
A    B    C
300  ken  601901 
400  Miki  500001
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a dictionary with a single key `'node'` and a list of dictionaries as value of that key. You can access the list of dictionaries and convert them to a dataframe as follows

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'node': [{u'A': 300, 'B': u'Ken', u'C': 101901}, {u'A': 400, u'B': u'Miki', u'C': 500001}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d['node'])
print(df)
```

Output

```
     A     B       C
0  300   Ken  101901
1  400  Miki  500001
```